# A question of vaadin starter pack license

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-spring-boot

I have downloaded the source code for vaadin bakery app. It uses commercial components. However, if I remove those component from the code(if possible at all), can I use the code and distribute it without violating any license?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, IMHO this is not possible. Quoted from the [overview page](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/bakeryflow/overview.html#getting-started):

> A paid Pro or Prime subscription is required for creating a new software project from a Starter template. After its creation, results can be used, developed and distributed freely, but licenses for the used commercial components are required during development. The Starter or its parts cannot be redistributed as a code example or template. For full terms, see the [Commercial Vaadin Template License](https://vaadin.com/license/cvtl-1.0).

So, the license is not about the components itself, but the template.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer :)